# How to pass a SOAP header from a client to a web service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

I have a client in C# and the Web Service must receive a certificate header. I don't know how to add the header to the Web Service. This is my code:

```
// Define a SOAP header by deriving from the SoapHeader base class.
// The header contains just one string value.
public class MyHeader : SoapHeader
{
    public string MyValue;
}

public partial class Service: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    MyWebService ESClient = new MyWebservice();
    private static String TAG_CERTIFICATE = "MxIFZjFCBFa...";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
        CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();

        MyHeader header = new MyHeader();

        // Populate the values of the SOAP header.
        header.MyValue = TAG_CERTIFICATE;

        //HOW CAN I ADD THIS CERTIFICATE TO MY ESCLIENT WEB SERVICE?????

        //remSolSal is the response of the Web Service
        remSolSal response= new remSolSal();
        //remDatSol is the method of the Web Service and getRemSolEnt the parameters that I send in another function
        response = ESClient.remDatSol(getRemSolEnt());
    }
```

The XML model certificate:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sol="url...">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <certificate>
            JgsJSP6Ql8f........
        </certificate>
```

Also, I have a client in Java that makes what I have to do in C#. It uses a this funtion to add the header, where paramName is "certificate" and paramContent is the value "JgsJSP6Ql8f........":

```
 /**
 * This method adds a custom header to message.
 * 
 * @param paramName
 */
private static void addHeaderParam(String paramName, String paramContent) {
    try {
        List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
        Header dummyHeader = new Header(new QName(TARGETNAMESPACE,
                paramName), paramContent, new JAXBDataBinding(String.class));
        headers.add(dummyHeader);

        // client side:
        ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(
                Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the properties of the object that `getRemSolEnt()` returns. See if it has a property for the header.

Comment: @JohnSaunders he needs to use the WCF API to do this, it can't just be assigned to the request object.

Comment: @moarboilerplate: if he's using a `SoapHeader`, then he's using a Web Reference, not a Service Reference, so no WCF.

Comment: True, but it appears that is just some test code in an attempt to achieve what he's asking...

Comment: Are you using a service reference, or a web reference?

Comment: Service reference, but I can change it. I use SR because the Visual Studio says that WR is from framework 2.0

Comment: No, keep using a service reference, but service references don't use `SoapHeader`.

Comment: You should be using a service reference unless you have a very specific need for using a webreference

Comment: Also, can you ask the developers of the service? Since you're this new, you may be using the terminology incorrectly. I'm not sure you need to add a SOAP Header. You may just need to properly configure the certificate in the client configuration.

Comment: @JohnSaunders My guess is OP's trying to consume a service that uses WS-Security or a similar standard for authentication that requires specific elements in the header. The .NET Framework can generate all of this for OP via client/endpoint/behavior configuration without him having to mangle his SOAP header unless he has very custom header requirements (been there...)

Comment: @moarboilerplate: that's my guess as well, but I'm trying to find out if we're guessing correctly.

Comment: I have expanded the information. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I used the class ClientMessageInspector to modify SOAP message:

```
public class ClientMessageInspector : System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IClientMessageInspector
{
    #region IClientMessageInspector Members

     public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
     {

     }

     public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
     {
         CustomMessageHeader header = new CustomMessageHeader();

         request.Headers.Add(header);

         return null;
     }

     #endregion
 }

/// <summary>
/// Represents a custom message header.
/// </summary>
public class CustomMessageHeader : MessageHeader
{
    private const string HeaderName = "CustomHeader";
    private const string HeaderNamespace = "";

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of the message header.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The name of the message header.</returns>
    public override string Name
    {
        get { return HeaderName; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the namespace of the message header.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The namespace of the message header.</returns>
    public override string Namespace
    {
        get { return HeaderNamespace; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the header content is serialized using the specified XML writer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">
    /// An <see cref="T:System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter" /> that is used to serialize the header contents.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="messageVersion">
    /// The object that contains information related to the version of SOAP associated with a message and its exchange.
    /// </param>
    protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("certificate", "JgsJSP6Ql8f........");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many, many ways to achieve what you're asking for and it depends on how your client is set up and how you want to maintain this. Are you using a service reference? Do you want to manage this in configuration or code? The easiest way to just plunk in a custom header is to use the `<headers>` element in your endpoint configuration in your config as referenced here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731749(v=vs.110).aspx

I personally recommend not putting the definition of your cert in your app but storing it in your server's keystore. You can then reference the certificate in a behavior applied to your client. You can also pull out the certificate with code and do what you need to by referencing the ESClient.ClientCredentials object.